# Stop Recursion in Blocks

Tags: objective-c, recursion, block, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

So I am dealing with networking with cookie authentication. If I get a 401 or 406 for Unauthorized, then I know the cookie has expired (valid for 1 HR), so I login with a stored token to get a new cookie. Once i do that, I want to try the call again, so I do a recursive call on the block. In an unknown case that if I continue to get 401 or 406 after a successful cookie refresh, it will infinitely recurse. I only want it to try one more time. How do I stop it?

I tried to setting the `requestID` to -1 after the first call and set in the if statement that `if(requestID == -1)` don't recurse. But since requestID is a block variable, it throws exception "Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier`

```
+ (void)fullRequestWithBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *fullRequest, NSError *error))block forID: (NSString*) requestID forUID: (NSString *) userID{

NSString *pathSuffix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GetRequestInfo?requestId=%@&userId=%@", requestID, userID];
[[AFAppAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:pathSuffix parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"false" forKey:@"include_entities"] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

    id innerJSON = [JSON objectForKey:@"d"];
    //NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSMutableDictionary *requestData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:innerJSON];

    [requestData removeObjectForKey:@"requestor"];
    [requestData removeObjectForKey:@"shortDesc"];
    [requestData removeObjectForKey:@"fullDesc"];

    if (block) {
        block([NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:fullDescription], nil);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if ([[[error localizedDescription] substringFromIndex:[[error localizedDescription] length] - 3] isEqualToString:@"406"])
    {
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *storedToken = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"storedToken"];

        [Login tokenLoginIDWithBlock:^(NSString *userID, NSError *error)
        {
             if (!error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Reaunthenciated User with ID: %@", userID);

                     [self fullRequestWithBlock:^(NSDictionary *requests, NSError *error) {
                         if (!error) {
                             if (block) {
                                 block([NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:requests], nil);
                             }
                         }
                         else{
                             block([NSDictionary dictionary], error);
                         }

                     } forID:requestID forUID:userID];

                 }
                 else{
                     block([NSDictionary dictionary], error);
                 }
             } forToken:storedToken];

        }
    }
    else if (block) {
        block([NSDictionary dictionary], error);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: The type of the Block seems to be fully under your control, so  can't you just add an argument `BOOL retryOnFailure` for this?

Comment: @JoshCaswell yea, I guess I could. Was wondering if there was a way to do it within the block without having to add new arguments.

Comment: A variable in the outer scope with the `__block` specifier would do it too, but I would go for the argument.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thank you, I added an argument. If you would like to put in your answer, I can checkmark it :).

Comment: Will do when I get a chance. Glad I could help.